# Logit model - none of the cases vary on one predictor

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, multivariable, separation

What do you do with a categorical predictor (e.g. Black-White-Hispanic) in a logistic model when none of the cases are White, but about half the population studied is? You have to drop this predictor since the logit model cannot handle this, but you think it is important to talk about.... I was told "this is not a statistical relationship" but obviously there is strong evidence of a relationship. Indeed, the relationship would have to be weaker in order to be studied. There must be a name for this situation, and references discussing it, but I'm not sure how to look it up.

This would be like saying you can't prove women are more likely to go into labor than are men unless a man goes into labor.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! The name for the situation is "separation", & there's no reason to say the logit model can't handle it. Maximum-likelihood gives infinite odds ratio estimates, which might well be all right; for some other methods see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/).

Comment: In Stata and some other software packages, no results will be given. However, a friend mentions Firth logistic regression, which can handle this situation. I tried this with both Stata and R, and only R had enough memory.